# In Vue2, how to remove observor functionality from object to save in cookie

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code fragment and would like to strip the observer functionality from the user.accounts object. How would I do that? `this.$cookies` is a reference to my `vue-cookies` instance

```
setUserAccount(user, account){
  // var accounts = Object.assign({},user.accounts)
  this.$cookies.set('AUTH_TOKEN', user.authHash);
  this.$cookies.set('CURRENT_ACCOUNT', user.id);
  this.$cookies.set('ACCOUNTS', user.accounts);
  console.log(user.accounts);
},
```

Comment: Changing its prototype to plain object could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the object to a JSON string.  That will remove all the Vue observer mechanisms.

```
const strAccounts = JSON.stringify(user.accounts)
this.$cookies.set('ACCOUNTS', strAccounts);
```

And to convert it back (without the observer functionality).

```
JSON.parse(strAccounts);
```

The only caveat is you need to watch out for `circular references` in your object, and `functions` will not get serialized.